# How to measure and plot the voltage of a capacitor over time?

Tags: ltspice

[image: Picture of my LT Spice Circuit I am trying to measure the voltage of the capacitor over time]

Hi,

I tried searching and could not find anything (this might honestly be so basic of a question that I couldn't find it). How do I measure the voltage of this capacitor and plot it over time? My circuits class literally just told us to download LT Spice and use it to simulate stuff and has given us no information on how to actually do that. Would very much appreciate any help right now.

Thank you

PS: On a Mac running Catalina and using version XVII of LT Spice

Comment: This site isn't a support group for LTSpice.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with the Mac version, but hopefully this is good enough to get you going.  What happens if you right-click (or ctrl+click) on the `.op` text on the schematic?  If it doesn't give you a fancy UI to change it to "Transient" and just lets you edit the raw text...then try changing it to `.tran 3`.  This tells it to run a time-domain simulation for 3 seconds.  If you want more precise data points, you have to change it to something like `.tran 0 3 0 1m` which would still run for 3 seconds but force a time-point calculation every 1 millisecond (called "maximum timestep" in the UI).

After the simulation runs you can probe voltages by clicking on any of the wires in the circuit, probe currents by clicking on any of the components in the circuit, or probe wattages by holding down `alt` before clicking on components in the circuit.  Voltages are given with respect to where you put the ground symbol.  If you need to get a voltage across a component you can click and hold on one node, then drag to the other node and release the click.

Also, your PWL source is kinda goofy.  Based on the context...it appears you might want it to say `PWL(0 0 1 4)` instead.

Oh, and last thing I noticed is that you can't use the carrot `^` symbol like that for your capacitor and inductor values.  You can use `8e-3` to represent \$8 \cdot 10^{-3}\$ but I think it's better to get used to using `m` for milli, and `u` for micro.  Check the program's help section for more info regarding this.  I'm not comfortable assuming the help document ships with the Mac version, so here's an online cached version: http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/A_General_Structure_and_Conventions.htm

Here is my recreation of your circuit.  I have plotted both the voltage and the current across the inductor.

[image]